# GitHub repo to track Postman request changes?

Tags: git, github, postman

When I make a change to a Postman request and then go to close the tab and get "Save Changes?" sometimes I don't remember what I changed.

I know I can import / export collections and put them in a repo to track changes but... anyone know if I can automatically track these changes by adding a GitHub repo in the location where Postman stores all my request/collection/environment/etc data?  I poked around in Program Files and also in C:\Users[my-user-name]\AppData\Local\Postman\ but I was unable to find any files that looked like collection json files or any other request data files that might be useful to track.

So I guess I create a repo and export collection json files to that repo location but if anyone knows a better way without that manual step, it would be much appreciated. Another possible solution might be some way to auto-export these collections every so often or when I make a change to a request.

Thanks!

Comment: What you asked for is [under paid plan](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collaborating-in-postman/using-workspaces/changelog-and-restoring-collections/#viewing-collection-activity).